# Missing number error when using the scrbook document class LuaLaTeX

Tags: errors, luatex, koma-script, scrbook

I'm working on a book of chants, using gregorio. The gregorio package requires LuaLaTeX. To simplify the issue, however, I narrowed the error down with this sample .tex file:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\maketitle
Lorem Lipsum
\end{document}
```

Compiling with LaTeX works fine, but when I try it with LuaLaTeX, it produces the following errors:

```
***snip***
)) (./test.aux)
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
p
l.2 \begin{document}

? 
! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
p
l.2 \begin{document}

? 
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
\begingroup 
l.2 \begin{document}

? 
! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
\begingroup 
l.2 \begin{document}

? 
-------------------
```

The output .pdf file has this text at the top of the page:

```
pagewidth=pageheight=
```

Am I fighting a pointless battle? I can use the {article} document type without issue, but the {scrbook} seems more appropriate. If there's no simple solution, I'll just go with article, but... Any advice?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Which version of LuaTeX do you use?

Comment: Which KOMA-Script version do you use? There was a bug in version 3.20 (I can reproduce your problem with this version). But current version is 3.21. If you can not update, then try to load package `luatex85`.

Comment: Your sample compiles fine for me both with `latex` and `lualatex`. Maybe try deleting your `.aux` file before recompiling.

Comment: Thanks, esdd (and everyone else)! That solved it. I'm using MacTex 2016, which likely has a prior version of KOMA-Script. Including
\usepackage{luatex85}
allowed even my gregorio file to compile without errors.
I'll look into updating KOMA-Script as well.

Comment: Updating KOMA-Script also worked seamlessly. For other users of MacTex 2016, this can be done very simply by typing the following in a terminal window (all on one line):

tlmgr install --reinstall --repository http://www.komascript.de/repository/texlive/2016 koma-script

Answer (score 6):

There was a bug in package `typearea` version 3.20 which is part of the KOMA-Script bundle and used by all KOMA-Script classes. See [Bekannte Probleme und Änderungen in KOMA-Script 3.20](http://www.komascript.de/release3.20) (German).

It is already **fixed in current version 3.21**. So if you update your KOMA-Script, your MWE will compile:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}[2016/06/14]
\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\maketitle
Lorem Lipsum
\end{document}
```

---

Workarounds if you have to use **version 3.20**:

If you do not want to change the default paper size (A4), set option `pagesize=false`:

```
\documentclass[pagesize=false]{scrbook}
\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\maketitle
Lorem Lipsum
\end{document}
```

Alternativly you can load package `luatex85`:

```
\documentclass[pagesize=false]{scrbook}
\usepackage{luatex85}
\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\maketitle
Lorem Lipsum
\end{document}
```